# jQuery function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

Lets say that I want to turn the paragraph elements red when I mouseover the corresponding link elements.

Why would the following code not work and what is the simplest alternative?

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {   
$("a").eq(i).mouseover(function(){
$("p").eq(i).css({"color":"red"})  
})
}
```

Need simple explanation.

Comment: because `for` is not a blocking call.

Comment: Please explain. Any help greatly appreciated. What should I write?

Comment: @NedHulton See the answer. If you can provide the html, there will be another easy ways to do this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/drqry6mk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to loop through the elements. Do like this,

```
$("a").mouseover(function() {
    $("p").eq($('a').index(this)).css("color", "red");
});
```